# Dependabot rebase does use the updated workflows

Tags: github, github-actions, dependabot

I have this GitHub action that does matrix testing on node 10, 12, 14. Got some failed dependabot PR because some packages have dropped support for node 10. I decided to drop it as well and made a change to the GitHub action directly on main.

Then did "@dependabot rebase" but then it still runs the GitHub action with node 10. ‍♂️

Example

https://github.com/Norfeldt/react-kitchen-sink/pull/163

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that there was a branch rule setting the node version 10 as a required test to pass before merging.

Hope this help others.